cordova.platformId returning as "browser" on android
I'm trying to write some mobile specific code in my cordova android app. My content src is an index.html where I have my JS code.
When I check cordova.platformId, it returns "browser", even if running on Android. Using cordova 12.0.0.

I'm no expert, but if you are using the cordova-plugin-device plugin, the value you are looking for should be in the property platform not platformid.
excerpt from the documentation (12.x):
// Depending on the device, a few examples are:
//   - "Android"
//   - "browser"
//   - "iOS"
//   - "WinCE"
//   - "Mac OS X"
//
var devicePlatform = device.platform;


Thank you for the reply. I did try the output of the plugin as well, and it still returned browser instead of android. I believe it has something to do with Android's permissions but I don't know which one to enable.

I haven't tested it yet , but it could be the READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE link to doc. it is also mentioned in the cordova docs. What android Version are you currently running/testing on?

@turtlesky I just tested the basic app (after updating all my tools npm , sdk, ...) And in the emulator, both cordova.platformId and device.platform output "ANDROID". Without setting any special permissions. (cordova version 12.0 and Android API 35)

Thanks for the reply. I am using Android API 34 because the docs said that was the latest compatible version.  Can you go through the steps you did to to use Android API 35?

Well I was Just update all my tools (installed newest Android Studio, following this guide and on setting up the SDK I selected the highest version of the 35 API). Then basically I executed this commands cordova create,  cordova platform add android, cordova plugin add , cordova build and cordova emulate android. (basically the cordova helloWorld ) . Side note I had to downgrade my Java from Version 22.

the cordova installation/setup guide is pretty extensive, some version numbers didn't match, but updating my setup was pretty easy. (even though I used a windows computer)
